# Asynchronous AJAX call freezes page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

A client recently contacted me about a new issue on a site I developed and installed several months ago. Hopefully someone with a little more knowledge of AJAX's inner workings can help me out.

On [this page](http://www.fitzpatrickmusic.net/music/), an AJAX call is made when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page to retrieve more posts and append them to the list. The code behind it is relatively simple:

```
function getnextposts() { 
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://fitzpatrickmusic.net/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: ({ action: 'getNextPosts', counter: pagecounter, postsretrieve: posts_retrieve }),
    success: function(data) {
        $("#loadingindicator").fadeOut(250);
        if ( $(data).length == 0 ) {
            $("#nomoreposts").delay(500).fadeIn(250);
        } else {
            $(data).hide().appendTo('.edd_downloads_list');
            download_list_filter_check();
            download_list_length_check();
            $(window).data('ajaxready', true);
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        $("#loadingindicator").fadeOut(250);
        $("#errorretrieve").delay(500).fadeIn(250);
        return false;
    }   
});
```

`download_list_filter_check()` and `download_list_length_check()` are helper functions that allow the AJAX call to cycle through the database and apply custom filters.

If you access this page in Chrome, IE, or mobile Safari, and try to activate this functionality by scrolling to the bottom of the list, you will notice the problem: the function runs briefly, then the entire site freezes for up to 10 or more seconds, then finally loads the new posts.

Here is what I know:

- This does not occur in Firefox or desktop Safari.
- I re-set up the development site, which is run by identical code, on my own server. The problem does not occur when viewing this site in any browser. ([See for yourself](http://andrewfishel.com/current/craig/build/music/))
- The client does not know when specifically this started happening, so I'm not sure if it's the result of a Wordpress or plugin update (though testing on the dev site seems to rule this out).

As I said before, AJAX is not something I'm familiar with. I'm not sure where to begin with diagnosing this problem, given its many specific conditions. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles across this, I turned off the AJAX call altogether and set the page to load all of the content at once. Obviously not ideal for loading time, but better than a completely frozen page. Still open to any suggestions as to how to fix an AJAX call that only freezes certain browsers when run from a particular server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery 1.5 or higher, it provides you another approach to address this. That is using Deferred and Promise for asynchronous calls.

[Avoiding nested asynchronous calls in JS](https://coderwall.com/p/kfx9pa/avoiding-nested-asynchronous-calls-in-js)

[Understanding JQuery.Deferred and Promise](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I brought my code up to date with this newer approach, and unfortunately it doesn't appear to have changed anything. It still works perfectly on my test server and freezes every time on the live site, despite having identical code. I'm beginning to suspect that this is an issue with the client's server and not something I can address from the front end. Do you have any insight into any back end issues that might be behind this?

Comment: I looked at into script on your site (`getnextposts()` func) and did a small performance test of outer ajax (`action: 'getNextPosts`), I run 3 times and got the result of second passed: 17.28, 20.393 and 18.681. The everage of them is 18.78s. You see, it seems you are performing a very long query task. Maybe you tested on your local machine, so the querying is fast because it does not depend on the NW connection but different in the go-live env.

Comment: So to troubleshoot this issue I recommend you 1st revise the `getnextposts` procedure and run it directly by DB tool then measure processing time, it shouldn't greater than 3s, 2nd is check the NW connection speed. I have not test the func `download_list_filter_check` and `download_list_length_check ` yet but I think they have no problem, but you should also check again. Hope that will help you find the causes quickly.

Comment: My testing did not take place on a local machine - it occurred on a remote server and depended on a network connection. See the links in my original post. Except for a few extra posts added since the live site was launched, the databases are identical, as is the code making the query. The only difference is location of the database - the client's remote server versus my remote server. What could cause the query to run slowly on one server, on certain browsers, but not another?